# Rails: Serialization of custom class for flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure out how flash messages in RoR insist on being serialized for the next page view. When setting a simple type to e.g. flash[:notice], all is well to get it across to the next page view. When I however try and set the value of flash[:notice] to a custom class, it serializes only the properties:

```
flash[:notice] = Info.notice("Content...", "Title")
```

... equates to ...

```
{"type"=>"notice", "content"=>"Content...", "title"=>"Title"}
```

... which has no knowledge of the class it serialized. One solution I found was to use .to_yaml before doing a redirect, and then use YAML.load at the later step, but I don't find that viable.

So my question is, how would I be able to make sure that it automatically serialize this object, to properly be deserialized at a later stage?

Rails: 4.2.5.1,
Ruby: 2.2.4p230

Thanks

Comment: why don't you think YAML is a proper solution? in general i'd say: "do not put things into flash that are not simple hashes", but hey, we've all tried to shoot ourselves in the foot, haven't we!

Comment: Because I would need to apply to_yaml in all places where I want this functionality, rather than have it centralized